# Divide char* into few variables

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I have some char array: `char char[8]` which containing for example two ints, on first 4 indexes is first int, and on next 4 indexes there is second int.

```
char array[8] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};
int a = array[0-3]; // =1;  
int b = array[4-8]; // =1;
```

How to cast this array to two int's?

There can be any other type, not necessarily int, but this is only some example:

I know i can copy this array to two char arrays which size will be 4 and then cast each of array to int. But i think this isn't nice, and breaks the principle of clean code.

Comment: I can't begin to understand why you want to do this, but `memcpy` might help you...

Comment: You can't just cast the `char*` to an `int*` because of endianness.

Comment: It looks like you want some magic to happen. No magic in this world, unfortunately. You will have to write a function to do the conversion.

Comment: @c650: i have char array with some variables there, and now i want do "decode" this into variables with good typ: int, longlong, double.

Comment: memcpy can build first int, but how to do this second?

Comment: What value will `a` be for `array[8] = {1,2,3,4,0,0,0,1};`? Is it `1234`?

Comment: Will it always be 4 values each?

Comment: @kaylum it dosent matter, a can be another char* but how to pass this

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie nope

Comment: @MaciejWójcik I posted an answer.  All this seems to boil down to is a simple accumulation of values for a total.  The same assignment given to beginner programming students, just in disguise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your data has the correct endianness, you can extract blitable types from a byte buffer with `memcpy`:

```
int8_t array[8] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};
int32_t a, b;
memcpy(&a, array + 0, sizeof a);
memcpy(&b, array + 4, sizeof b);
```

While @Vivek is correct that `ntohl` can be used to normalize endianness, you have to do that as a second step.  Do not play games with pointers as that violates [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/103167) and leads to undefined behavior (in practice, either alignment exceptions or the optimizer discarding large portions of your code as unreachable).

```
int8_t array[8] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};
int32_t tmp;
memcpy(&tmp, array + 0, sizeof tmp);
int a = ntohl(tmp);
memcpy(&tmp, array + 4, sizeof tmp);
int b = ntohl(tmp);
```

Please note that almost all optimizing compilers are smart enough to not call a function when they see `memcpy` with a small constant count argument.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a little bit of the C++ algorithms, such as `std::accumulate`:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int getTotal(const char* value, int start, int end)     
{
    return std::accumulate(value + start, value + end, 0, 
                           [](int n, char ch){ return n * 10 + (ch-'0');});
}

int main()
{
    char value[8] = {'1','2','3','4','0','0','1','4'};
    int total1 = getTotal(value, 0, 4);
    int total2 = getTotal(value, 4, 8);
    std::cout << total1 << " " << total2;
}
```

Note the usage of `std::accumulate` and the lambda function.  All we did was have a running total, multiplying each subtotal by 10.  The character is translated to a number by simply subtracting `'0'`.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/OylpoO)

Comment: If the `char[]` contains ASCII text with fixed-width decimal numbers, then this would be a good approach.  I interpreted the question as having binary data not text, but it didn't actually say so this could be correct.

Comment: ^ same. I thought it was supposed to be more of a cast than an `atoi`.

Answer (score -1):

You can type cast the bytes from the array to an `int *`. Then dereferencing will cause 4 bytes to be read as an int. Then doing an ntohl, will ensure that the bytes in the int are arranged as per the host order.

```
char array[8] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};

int a = *((int *)array);  
int b = *((int *)&array[4]);

a = ntohl(a);  
b = ntohl(b);
```

This will set a and b to 1 on both little and big endian systems.

If the compiler is set for strict aliasing, memcpy could be used to achieve the same, as follows:

```
char array[8] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1};
int a, b;

memcpy(&a, array, sizeof(int));
memcpy(&b, array+4, sizeof(int));

a = ntohl(a);  
b = ntohl(b);
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior.  Strict aliasing allows you to access an `int` using `char*`, it does not allow you to access a `char[]` using `int*`.  Badness ensues.

Comment: It works on a little endian system. i just tried it out to double check. memcpy could be used as well.